# TLA+ sequence not being updated with Append or Tail calls

Tags: tla+

## The Problem

I'm playing around with [TLA+](https://learntla.com/introduction/), and thought I'd write the following clearly false specification in PlusCal:

```
---- MODULE transfer ----
EXTENDS Naturals, TLC, Sequences

(* --algorithm transfer

\* Simple algorithm:
\*  1. Start with a shared-memory list with one element.
\*  2. A process adds arbitrary numbers of elements to the list.
\*  3. Another process removes arbitrary numbers of elements from the list, 
\*     but only if the list has more than one item in it. This check is 
\*     applied just before trying to removing an element. 
\* Is it true that the list will always have a length of 1? 
\* You would expect this to be false, since the adder process can add more elements 
\* than the remover process can consume.

variables stack = <<0>>

process Adder = 0
  begin
      AddElement:
        stack := Append(stack, Len(stack));
        either goto AddElement
        or skip
        end either;
end process;

process Remover = 1
  begin
      RemoveElement:
        \* Pop from the front of the stack
        if Len(stack) > 1 then
            stack := Tail(stack);
        end if;
        either goto RemoveElement
        or skip
        end either;
end process;

end algorithm *)

IsStackAlwaysUnitLength == Len(stack) = 1

====
```

After checking `IsStackAlwaysUnitLength` as one of the temporal properties to report on, I expected TLA+ to mark this property as failed.

However, all states passed! Why is it not failing?

## Debugging Attempts

On debugging with `print` statements, I noticed the following odd behaviour:

```
process Adder = 0
  begin
      AddElement:
        print stack;
        print "Adder applied!";
        stack := Append(stack, Len(stack));
        print stack;
        print "Adder task complete!";
        \* Force 
        either goto AddElement
        or skip
        end either;
end process;

process Remover = 1
  begin
      RemoveElement:
        \* Pop from the front of the stack
        print stack;
        print "Remover applied!";
        if Len(stack) > 1 then
            stack := Tail(stack);
            print stack;
            print "Remover task complete!";
        else
            print "Remover task complete!";
        end if;
        either goto RemoveElement
        or skip
        end either;
end process;
```

yields in the debugging panel

```
<<0>>
"Adder applied!"
<<0>>
"Adder task complete!"
<<0>>
<<0>>
"Remover applied!"
"Remover applied!"
"Remover task complete!"
"Remover task complete!"
<<0>>
"Adder applied!"
<<0>>
"Adder task complete!"
```

I'm unsure why `stack := Append(stack, Len(stack));` and `stack := Tail(stack);` are not updating the global `stack` variable.

## Full TLA Specification Generated

```
---- MODULE transfer ----
EXTENDS Naturals, TLC, Sequences

(* --algorithm transfer

variables stack = <<0>>

process Adder = 0
  begin
      AddElement:
        stack := Append(stack, Len(stack));
        either goto AddElement
        or skip
        end either;
end process;

process Remover = 1
  begin
      RemoveElement:
        \* Pop from the front of the stack
        if Len(stack) > 1 then
            stack := Tail(stack);
        end if;
        either goto RemoveElement
        or skip
        end either;
end process;

end algorithm *)
\* BEGIN TRANSLATION
VARIABLES stack, pc

vars == << stack, pc >>

ProcSet == {0} \cup {1}

Init == (* Global variables *)
        /\ stack = <<0>>
        /\ pc = [self \in ProcSet |-> CASE self = 0 -> "AddElement"
                                        [] self = 1 -> "RemoveElement"]

AddElement == /\ pc[0] = "AddElement"
              /\ stack' = [stack EXCEPT ![0] = Append(stack, Len(stack))]
              /\ \/ /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![0] = "AddElement"]
                 \/ /\ TRUE
                    /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![0] = "Done"]

Adder == AddElement

RemoveElement == /\ pc[1] = "RemoveElement"
                 /\ IF Len(stack) > 1
                       THEN /\ stack' = [stack EXCEPT ![1] = Tail(stack)]
                       ELSE /\ TRUE
                            /\ stack' = stack
                 /\ \/ /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![1] = "RemoveElement"]
                    \/ /\ TRUE
                       /\ pc' = [pc EXCEPT ![1] = "Done"]

Remover == RemoveElement

Next == Adder \/ Remover
           \/ (* Disjunct to prevent deadlock on termination *)
              ((\A self \in ProcSet: pc[self] = "Done") /\ UNCHANGED vars)

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_vars

Termination == <>(\A self \in ProcSet: pc[self] = "Done")

\* END TRANSLATION

IsStackAlwaysUnitLength == Len(stack) = 1

====
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you've hit a PlusCal bug! And also an edge case that's not a bug but still unintuitive. Let's start with the bug.

Sometimes when using PlusCal we want to have multiple processes share labels. We do this with a **procedure**. In order to make it all work the PlusCal translator adds an extra bookkeeping variable called `stack`. *Normally*, if the user defines a variable `foo` that conflicts with a generated variable `foo`, the translation renames one to `foo_`. In this case, since there was no conflict, there wasn't any renaming.* The bug is that the translator got confused and translated the variable *as if* it was supposed to be the bookkeeping `stack`. You can see this as it turned the append into

```
stack' = [stack EXCEPT ![0] = Append(stack, Len(stack))]
```

When it should just be

```
stack' = Append(stack, Len(stack))
```

You can fix this by **renaming `stack` to `mystack`.** That should get the spec behaving properly. But it will still pass: that's because you put `IsStackAlwaysUnitLength` as a *property* and not an *invariant*. As a temporal property, `IsStackAlwaysUnitLength` is true if it's true in the initial state. As an invariant, `IsStackAlwaysUnitLength` is true if it's true in *all* states.** YOu can get the spec to fail properly by **changing `IsStackAlwaysUnitLength` from a temporal property to an invariant** in the "what is the model" page.

*Actually in this case the translator won't rename `stack` if you add a procedure, it just throws an error. But that's still fail-safe.

**This is because TLC (the model checker) treats the invariant `P` as the temporal property `[]P`. It's syntactic sugar, basically.

Comment: That `stack` naming conflict is insane, haha. I hope not all TLA+ is like this.

Comment: It has some rough spots, but issues of that caliber are super rare. And IMO once you hit your stride, TLA+ is absolutely _incredible_. Like "changed my life" incredible. Welcome to formal methods!